# Angular.js - Convert string with special characters and numbers into Array and display with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am new to angular.js and I'm having an issue with converting string into array and displaying it with ng-repeat, so far i got this custom filter from [a stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32048201/how-to-split-a-string-and-use-in-ng-repeat) and the codes are:

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('globalModule', [])

    app.controller("SampleController", function($scope){

        $scope.data = "123abc123";
    }); 


    app.filter("spaceBreak", 
        function () {
            return function ( value ) {
                  if( !value.length ) return;
                      return value.split("");   
            }
        });
```

HTML:

```
 <body ng-controller="SampleController">
     <h4 id="id_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="value in data | spaceBreak"><span ng-bind="value"></span></h4>
</body>
```

My problem is, it converts and display properly if it is an alphabet(abc) or a number(123) alone, and if combined (abc123) or (123abc) still good, but if the data is number+alphabet+number (123abc123) it doesnt show anymore in ng-repeat. I am really lost and really need help. Hope someone can lend me an answer.

Comment: A little confused... so you would want the string `123abc123` to be split into an array and show up in your ng-repeat as `123`, `abc`, `123`?

Comment: Nope, I want to split it individually, like 1,2,3,a,b,c,1,2,3
splitting abc123 and 123abc has no issue, but with 123abc123 it doesnt show. i dont know why, same with characters, like !abc! it doesnt show in ng-repeat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the `track by $index` functionality. You code errors out because you have duplicates in your `$scope.data`. That filter isn't really doing anything for you, so you can just `ng-repeat` through your `$scope.data` string.

```js
var app = angular.module('globalModule', [])

app.controller("SampleController", function($scope){

  $scope.data = "123abc123"; 
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="globalModule">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="SampleController">
    <h4 id="id_{{$index}}" ng-repeat="value in data track by $index"><span ng-bind="value"></span></h4>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Nice answer, I didn't know that `ng-repeat` would iterate over strings too. One question, what is `lodash` being used for here?

Comment: Sorry, it's not. I autopilot add it to every snippet, haha. Will remove, thanks.

Comment: Also, for the OP, here is the [official Angular explanation](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/dupes) of why duplicates in an ng-repeat is a problem.

Comment: Ohh you save me man! thank you very much! Adding track by $index made it work thank youu